# I am unable to update currency automatically on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, currency, currency-rates

Automatic updates of foreign currency does not happen

Comment: Check my answer will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I created this extension https://github.com/thanhdv2811/Magento-2-Currency-Convert to update currency rate using other services to fix the magento currency auto-update issue

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 gives you the option to update currency rates from one of the three options:

- Yahoo Finance Exchange
- Fixer.io
- Webservicex

You need to specify which option you want to use for currency rates update. You also need to configure the update option you’ve selected.

**Step 1:** **Go to Stores => Configurations (under Settings).**

[image]

**Step 2: Click on Currency Setup tab from the left sidebar in General configuration settings.**

[image]

You’ll see Yahoo Finance Exchange, Fixer.io and Webservicex sections in the Currency Options page.

**Step 3: Expand the section you want to use for currency rate import.**

[image]

You’ll see the Connection Timeout in Seconds field in your selected import option.

Set the number of seconds for which your connection stays idle when trying to establish an import connection before it times out.

**Step 4: Expand the Scheduled Import Settings section.**

[image]

You’ll need to fill in the following details to schedule currency rates update import:

Enabled: Set this to “Yes” to automatically update currency rates.

Service: Select the service from where you want to update the currency rates.

Start Time: Set the time when your rate import should start.

Frequency: Set frequency of the rate updates. You can set the update frequency to:

- Daily
- Weekly
- Monthly

Error Email Recipient: Specify an email address, where a notification should be sent if there is an error in the rate import process.
Error Email Sender: Set which email should be used to send the error notification.
Error Email Template: Set which email template should be used for error notification email.

**Step 5: Click on Save Config button to save the currency rate update settings.**

[image]

You’ll be prompted to refresh invalidated cache types through system pop-up message.

After all run command:

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Thank You @NikunjVadariya 
However I am unable to work around with this. Could you please assist if I can share my login credentials with you?

Comment: @HuzanForbes my skype id : nikunj.vadariya

Comment: @HuzanForbes if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 latest version you usually face this problem. You can get latest currency rate using below module.

https://marketplace.magento.com/sanjay-module-custom-currency-updater.html